# Disable slider value talk back

Tags: android, slider, accessibility, talkback

I have a slider that has value in years. When I enable the talk back feature on samsung galaxy nexus 3, the talkback reads whatever is written in the content description and then says "slider 40%"...40% being the progress on the slider. I want to disable this percentage part of talkback. Not sure how to do it as I haven't written any code for android to read the progress. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can you just post the code where you enable the talk back feature or the code where you have used a slider for value in years?

Comment: put your code so we can help you..

Answer (score 1):

set         `app:labelBehavior="gone"` to achieve the desired behavior!
hope this helps other facing same!